# How to search a string in a diff

Tags: git, git-diff

How to find all the files that contain a change of a given substring in a diff?

Or in other words, how to filter the diff by a substring and showing only the files that contain that substring as a change (+ or -)?

Comment: Could you show a concrete example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `git diff -S<string>`, checkout the diffcore pickaxe documentation here : [diffcore pickaxe](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore.html#_diffcore-pickaxe%3A_for_detecting_addition/deletion_of_specified_string)